# How do i correct my Postgres sql insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below insert statement throws an error -

> Kernel error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"

What's wrong in the statement ?

```
insert into partner_sub_trans_types_mp
values (select MAX(id) + 1 from partner_sub_trans_types_mp , 46, 86)
```

This table partner_sub_trans_types_mp has got three columns:

1. id
2. partner_code
3. m_sub_transaction_types

Comment: Why not use an identity column? They have been invented for a reason. With `MAX(id) + 1` you get always NULL as long as the table is empty. And once there is an ID in the table two concurrent inserts (i.e. run at the same time) get the same ID.

Comment: This is  a horrible way to generate a new ID.

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT` needs to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
insert into partner_sub_trans_types_mp
values ((select MAX(id) + 1 from partner_sub_trans_types_mp), 46, 86)
```

However, you should listen to the recommendations above to use an *identity column* instead!